# How to read/write INI files Visual c++ 6.0 (MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to read/write INI files in VISUAL C++ 6.0 (with MFC)
I tried to load registry.hpp and CINIfiles and a few more but they don't exist in this version(because of constraints in the workplace I can't use the BOOST library).
So which way should work with INI files?

Comment: GetPrivateProfileString / WritePrivateProfileString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boost program options OR property tree to read .ini files.

Apart from that you can use windows API functionalities GetPrivateProfileString() and GetPrivateProfileInt().

Comment: Hey, I forgot to mention that because of constraints in the workplace I can't use the BOOST library.